# for loop returning empty values

Tags: python, for-loop

So the following code works fine, is for web scraping a newspaper, on a certain date (i.e. 01/04/2017), but when I create a daterange, and loop over each day I get empty values, below the code, and then I put the ´for loop´

```
url = 'http://servicios.lanacion.com.ar/archivo-f01/04/2017-c30'
sauce = uReq(url)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'html.parser')
date = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'titFecha'})
date = str(date)
fecha = '"titFecha">'
date = date[date.find(fecha)+len(fecha):date.find(fecha)+21]
day = date[:2]
month = date[3:5]
year = date[6:12]
print date

filename = 'La Nacion_%s_%s_%s.csv' % (day, month, year)
f = open(filename,'w')
headers = "Date, Title, Encabezado\n"
f.write(headers)

acumulados = soup.findAll('li',{'class':'acumulados'})
for acum in acumulados:
    title =  acum.a['href']
    #     title = title.text
    print title
    encabezado = acum.p
    #     encabezado = encabezado.text
    print encabezado,'\n'
    f.write(str(date) + ',' + str(title).replace(',',' ') + ',' + str(encabezado).replace(',',' ') + '\n')

f.close()
```

And here is the loop, probably is easy, but I am learning, still don't see these problems, thanks!

```
date_range = pd.date_range('2017-04-01',periods=2, freq='d')
date_range = date_range.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
for i in date_range:
    url = 'http://servicios.lanacion.com.ar/archivo-f%r-c30' % i
    sauce = uReq(url)
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'html.parser')
    date = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'titFecha'})
    date = str(date)
    fecha = '"titFecha">'
    date = date[date.find(fecha)+len(fecha):date.find(fecha)+21]
    day = date[:2]
    month = date[3:5]
    year = date[6:12]
    print date

    filename = 'La Nacion_%s_%s_%s.csv' % (day, month, year)
    f = open(filename,'w')
    headers = "Date, Title, Encabezado\n"
    f.write(headers)

    acumulados = soup.findAll('li',{'class':'acumulados'})
    for acum in acumulados:
        title =  acum.a['href']
        print title
        encabezado = acum.p
        print encabezado,'\n'
        f.write(str(date) + ',' + str(title).replace(',',' ') + ',' + str(encabezado).replace(',',' ') + '\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'get empty values'? Where? In the output file? What  about your `print` statements?

Comment: Narrow down the problem to a [MCVE]. Shouldn't have to repeat this instruction on every question!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the format of the i in the for loop is numpy.string_ not string, you can change `%r` to `%s` in the line `url`, and change the `strftime("%d/%m/%y")` to `strftime("%d/%m/%Y")` like below:

```
date_range = pd.date_range('2017-04-01',periods=2, freq='d')
date_range = date_range.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
for i in date_range:    
    url = 'http://servicios.lanacion.com.ar/archivo-f%s-c30' % i
```

Comment: that was exactly the mistake! the format ´strftime("%d/%m/%y")´ was returning the wrong string I need in my URL and that's why I was searching in a wrong link and that's why the BS object were empty. As soon as I changed to ´strftime("%d/%m/%Y")´, I got the expected results. Thanks @Tiny.D! and thanks to @BoundaryImposition it was very helpful to read about posting questions and debuging.